# Need to parameterize thread group, ramp up, loop count in jmeter, how to use CSV for this

Tags: jmeter

I want to run my jmeter scripts in the following manner:

```
Thread Count         Rampup      loop count
100                  10           20
150                  1            10
200                  1            10
```

I gave this data in CSV Data Set Config, tried to read it, but it is not read from CSV file for Thread Group level.

I don't want to copy the thread group and configure the above configuration.

Is there any way we can parameterize and use it

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, the number of threads and stuff are being initialized **before** any CSV files are being read.

You can use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to define number of users, iterations and ramp-up time

[image]

so you can run your test using a batch file or sequence of commands like:

```
jmeter -Jusers=100 -Jrampup=10 -Jloops=10 -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl \
&& jmeter -Jusers=150 -Jrampup=1 -Jloops=10 -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl \
etc.
```

---

Alternatively go for the [Open Model Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-model-thread-group) or any suitable alternative from [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) bundle

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I try those methods

Comment: through command line is works for me, thanks